# Work around on an unrooted LG 4

Tags: rooting, lg, bloatware

Had a rooted phone for years til and LG update bricked my last phone. Now I had to upgrade to an LG 4 ( Sprint is my carrier BTW) Problem is... I can't find the setting to enable USB debugging, nor, does it appear, that I can unlock the UICC. I like the phone so this isn't really a problem, but, I hate having the bloatware. (ie I would rather access facebook via the browser than keep this data-eater on my phone. Does anyone know how to work around this block so that I can remove the unwanted bloatware without rooting the phone?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your Facebook app a system app? You can't uninstall the System app without root access. What is your Android version?

Comment: Hi! Please note that this is not a forum but a Q&A site, so you need not to add any indication that an answer is found or this is a question or similar things. I've rolled back to original question for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I thought about posting this as an edit, but I feel an answer will better suit the community. Here is what I found.

To unlock the developer options on an LG4 Go into settings... about phone..Software info. Finally, tap "Build Number" 7 times. Now back out to the main menu and there will be a choice for Developer Options. From here you can enable USB debugging and enjoy all of the other tools available. Rooting the phone from this point is easy.